# Airflow not finding a local file

Tags: python, airflow

My local python script is finding the file just fine.
When I call it from my dag, it is not finding the file.
This is on an M1 Mac, for what that's worth.
And I am doing this within a Docker container.

I've tried creating a script with print statements confirming whether or not the file is found.
Additionally, I expect a returned Boolian value when the function is done running.

This is the script 'check_file.py'

```
import os


def check_file_exists():
    file_path = "./store_files_airflow/raw_store_transactions.csv"

    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        print(f"{file_path} exists!\n")
    else:
        print(f"{file_path} does not exist.\n")
    return os.path.isfile(file_path)
```

this is 'dag.py'

```
with DAG(
    "store_dag",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    template_searchpath=["/usr/local/airflow/sql_files"],
    catchup=True,
) as dag:
    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="check_file_exists", python_callable=check_file_exists, dag=dag
    )
```

I've omitted imports and superfluous text.

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, please let me know if I am leaving out key information?

Comment: What is your `AIRFLOW_HOME` value configured to be? The path `./store_files_airflow/raw_store_transactions.csv` might work in your local but not inside airflow docker coz the current directories might be different locations. Try to exec into the container and do an `ls`, `pwd` to find out which path you are in.

Comment: Thanks Vishal. I think you're onto something here. I'm following a tutorial with a docker file and docker-compose file. I see that they are using an AIRFLOW_HOME assignment. I will look into this and let you know if it is the solution!